# Using absolute path, FileNotFoundError

Tags: python, python-3.x, file-io, python-3.6

This is supposed to read the passed file aloud. When I pass an absolute path for whatever text file I'm reading, I get a FileNotFoundError. Works fine for local filenames. Any ideas?

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
from os import system

def text_to_speech(word):
  system('say %s' % word)

with open(input("Input File Path: ")) as fin:
  for line in fin:
      text_to_speech(line)
```

Here's the stack:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "timer.py", line 7, in <module>
    with open(input("Input File Path: ")) as fin:
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/Users/codeboy/Desktop/Project/test.txt '
```

Comment: Might it be the space in the end of the file path?

Comment: Oh boy *facepalm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an extra space at the end of it. Either remove that when you're inputting data or change the open line with:

```
with open(input("Input File Path: ").strip()) as fin:
```